# Table Pagination [Bootstrap - Django]

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a `django-bootstrap` project and I'm having some trouble with the bootstrap's table pagination, it won't appear on my template.
I'm using one of the default bootstrap tables with my own styles, and I wanted to ask you guys for your help to give my table the pagination it needs.

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:1200px; margin-left:-45px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header1"> </th>
      <th class="header1">ID Riesgo</th>
      <th class="header1">Código Riesgo</th>
      <th class="header1">Característica</th>
      <th class="header1">Evento</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for riesgos in riesgos %}
    <tr style="height: -2px;">
      <td style="text-align:center;">
        <div class name="checkboxWrapper">
          <input type="checkbox" id="check" hidden="true" style="margin-top: 10px;" />
          <label for="check" class="checkmark"></label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="color:#A9A9A9 ;">{{riesgos.id_ri}}</td>
      <td style="color:#A9A9A9;">{{riesgos.cod_ri}}</td>
      <td style="color:#A9A9A9;">{{riesgos.caracterisitica}}</td>
      <td style="color:#A9A9A9;">{{riesgos.evento}}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this snippet, table works fine and I added pagination for you in code.

For center `pagination` I added `d-flex justify-content-center` classes in your `nav` tag, feel free to remove it if you need `pagination` in the left side.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:1200px; margin-left:-45px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header1"> </th>
      <th class="header1">ID Riesgo</th>
      <th class="header1">Código Riesgo</th>
      <th class="header1">Característica</th>
      <th class="header1">Evento</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- {% for riesgos in riesgos %} -->
    <tr style="height: -2px;">
      <td style="text-align:center;">
        <div class name="checkboxWrapper">
          <input type="checkbox" id="check" hidden="true" style="margin-top: 10px;" />
          <label for="check" class="checkmark"></label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="color:#A9A9A9 ;">{{riesgos.id_ri}}</td>
      <td style="color:#A9A9A9;">{{riesgos.cod_ri}}</td>
      <td style="color:#A9A9A9;">{{riesgos.caracterisitica}}</td>
      <td style="color:#A9A9A9;">{{riesgos.evento}}</td>
      <!-- {% endfor %} -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<nav class="d-flex justify-content-center" aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wanted to ask you how many registers does it show before passing to another page?

Comment: What you mean by register?

Comment: I mean that the table is going to be filled with data, i just filled the table with a lot of registers (like 20) and my table is still showing them all at the first page. By any chance u know what to do? Thank u!!!

Comment: Loop `page-item`, like you loop table, above is just static HTML.

Comment: Oh, i understand. Okay, will try. Thank u!